# Packing maven submodules into single archive

Tags: java, maven

I have maven project which is split into several submodules. Structure looks like this:

- **base** - which is parent for all submdules
- **base/bom** - bill of materials
- **base/core** - application logic and public interfaces
- **base/gui-impl** - implementation of gui (depends on core)

I would like to add another module which would be responsible for packing the whole application into a single runnable JAR. Unfortunately if I simply create that submodule and define dependencies to the other modules, I'll get jar containing other jars (not just compiled classes). By the way - core will be packed twice (because gui-impl also depends on core).

How to solve this problem? Is there any maven plugin which could help me?

Comment: What plugin do you use for packaging? What you described does not sound like a standard maven packaging outcome (jar containing other jars). It is usually all the jars combined into one and there are no duplications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single executable jar that includes all the dependencies use [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). No matter how tangled they are you will not get any duplicated imports. Also you don't have to create a separate submodule for that, you can do it in the already existing top level one (but that's up to you really).

Other notable plugins for that purpose are [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) for complex packaging needs and [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/), which does not produce a single jar but a nice directory layout with bin/, conf/, lib/ directories and execution scripts, which I prefer for end user applications. What I usually do is use appassembler to make the app directories and then pack them into tar.gz or .zip using assembly-plugin for distibution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers but I figured out what was wrong. Inside my packing submodule I set packaging to JAR, expecting it to be final, runnable product :< 
I read about maven-assembly-plugin (as miljanm mentioned) and then I changed packaging to pom and added configuration for this plugin. maven-assembly-plugin is all what I want, it allows me to package all submodules into single runnable jar without packing one jar into another and without duplications.
Thank you!